# Regex to match the a string in a word, and that word must appear at the last word of the sentence

Tags: regex

i want to match the pattern (i.e. Error/exception) which should be at the end of the sentence/line(have multiple lines).

ex:

```
ABC.sfgs.maxRetriesOnError(StringNameSpaceBinding)
ABC.jjg.clm.fg.sg(sd/ifgap|sgf.xml#sf)
NullPointerException
numberError
```

from the above string, it should match both NullPointerException and numberError

i tried this -

```
(/\w*[eE]rror\s|\w*[eE]xception\s/)
```

, but it is not working properly

Comment: It matches right? https://regex101.com/r/p2K4Lg/1 Note that you are expecting a whitespace char at the end.

Comment: it can be anything, whitespace or tab or new line or multiple spaces

Comment: Perhaps like this `\b\w*[Ee](rror|xception)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/VJ9x2L/1

Comment: it is actually working in online regex website. but, i'm trying in jenkins groovy script, there it is not matching :(

Comment: Perhaps you have to double escape the backslash `\\b\\w*[Ee](rror|xception)(?!\\S)`

Comment: no ! its not helping...thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you add the code to the question that is not working for you? Else try `(?:^|\s)\w*[Ee](rror|xception)(?:$|\s)` if lookarounds are not supported https://regex101.com/r/dn14s7/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird  here is the piece of code,

Comment: new File("/datafs/job/var/jenkins2/workspace/build.log").splitEachLine("\n"){ line ->
            if(line =~ /.*installation\sfinished.*/) {
                println "Command executed successfully"
            }else {
                regPatterns = [/\b\w*[Ee](rror|xception)(?!\S)/]
                for(item in regPatterns){
                    if (line =~ item){
                        println "Exception or Error found in command output : $line"
                    }
                }
            }
         }

Comment: If I read [this page](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/#find-operator) I think the code looks good. Can you test with a single line and the regex? Did you print all the lines that it is checking to see if it reaches the code?

Comment: yes i tried, not working

Comment: if i use this regex - /\b\w*[Ee]rror/ to only match the line with error. it will list out all the line which contains error ( ex: abcVerbundErrorRedirection ) but i dont want this.

Comment: This does match when the lines ends with an exception or error https://regex101.com/r/RPEgYf/1 `\b\w*[Ee](rror|xception)$`

Comment: its working in online regex websites but sadly not on the groovy scrpt

Comment: What is the full line in the groovy script that it should work on? You said that this does work `/\b\w*[Ee]rror/` but for all lines right?

Comment: basically, i have a log file.
if this file contains any error/exception at the end of string(like FileNotFoundException) it should fail the build.

in my case, in the logs i have words like maxRetriesOnError(StringNameSpaceBinding)

as per the regex - /\b\w*[Ee]rror/ ...it is matching all the words

Answer (score 0):

try this:    `/.*([Ee](?:xception|rror))$/gm`